# I want to convert any image in my flutter project to qr code

Tags: flutter, dart, web, qr-code

Hello I was wondering I’m using flutter web in my project and I noticed that when hovering over an image and right clicking, I don’t get the option to generate qr code for this image, but in many websites it’s there! So how do I implement this in flutter? Is there a way? Thanks in advance!

I tried using qr_picker package but it didn’t help me

Comment: Hello yazan. Why do you need to convert an image to a qr code? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Hello @Axel thanks for replying, well in my project's requirements, each image in the report collection needs to be convertible to qr_code, since the company wants this, they want each report to be converted to a pdf, and instead of images, they want the images qr codes, we're using firebase cloud store

Comment: Converting even a low resolution image to a QR is impossible, as qr codes contain very small data compared to images.
What would make sense is converting the image's path or url to qr code.

Comment: @Axel yes that's exactly what I mean, to convert the path, do you know how?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert the image's path to a QR Code, you can check out [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_flutter).

It's extremly simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The QR-code generation in your browser is most probably an extension that takes the link in the `<img>`-tag on normal websites and creates a qr-code with that.

the problem is flutter (web) doensn't use standard html elements to lay out its contents but a custom renderer.

So your only way is to wrap your image in another widget that generates the qr-code for your users (use the one axel mentioned).
If you use `Image.network` thats easy, just reuse your url.
If your image is stored differently tho, you need to upload it anywhere accessable beforehand, or create [deeplinks](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation/deep-linking) to a view with that image